# 最大値を出力するプログラムで最大値が毎回３２７６３という値になる

Tags: c

最大値を関数を使って求めるコードを書いたのですが、毎回同じ値が出力されます。
また、「return max」を「return 1」とすると「１」が出力されます。
コードです

```
#include <stdio.h>

int choiceMax(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int max = 0;
    
    if (x > y) {
        max = x;
    } else {
        max = y;
    }
    
    if (x > z) {
        max = x;
    } else {
        max = z;
    }
    
    if (y > z) {
        max = y;
    } else {
        max = z;
    }
    
    return max;
}
        
int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    
    scanf("%d%d&d", &x, &y, &z);
    printf("%d\n", choiceMax(x, y, z));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `scanf` の引数に打ち間違いがあります。このせいで `z` が意図しない値になってしまい、今回はたまたま 32763 が毎回表示されるようになってしまったのでしょう。
- 更に、`choiceMax` 関数の実装に間違いがあります。たとえば `x = 3`, `y = 2`, `z = 1` のときにコードがどのように実行されるか 1 行ずつ想像してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

> scanf("%d%d&d", &x, &y, &z);

これ間違ってます。
zには値が入りません。

でもひとつ、ローカル変数は最初はでたらめな値が入っています

Answer (score 2):

y_waiwaiさんの回答通りですが、補足すると`scanf`は戻り値として読み込んだ項目数を返します。
戻り値を無視せず確認していれば、期待していた`3`ではなく`2`が返されるため、プログラムの誤りに気づけたかもしれません。